# Getting ValueError when I am trying to convert json to dataframe using python pandas module

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am having a nested json. I am trying to convert this json to dataframe in pandas

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('scratch.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

I am getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nitesh/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2019.3/scratches/nitesh.py", line 8, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  File "/Users/nitesh/.local/share/virtualenvs/nitesh-ovXpZdv7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 435, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/nitesh/.local/share/virtualenvs/nitesh-ovXpZdv7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 254, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/nitesh/.local/share/virtualenvs/nitesh-ovXpZdv7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 64, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "/Users/nitesh/.local/share/virtualenvs/nitesh-ovXpZdv7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 365, in extract_index
    raise ValueError("arrays must all be same length")
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

How to convert nested json to dataframe

Comment: Please show what the json file contains. Otherwise we'd all just be guessing

Comment: If it's a JSON, you should be using `json_normalize`, and not `pd.DataFrame`. But can't tell without looking at the JSON, please share a sample of the json that's not an image.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, but you could just use pd.read_json("file.json"). Like they said it is probably the json file.